# jqgrid - icons not displaying - version issue?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

**I was earlier using the following versions:**

- Jquery - 1.4.3
- jqGrid - 4.1.2

**Now I'm using the following versions:**

- Jquery - 1.6.4
- jqGrid - 4.3.1

**Using the latest versions, I've noticed the following:**

- the columns sorting icons of jqgrid are not displayed by default. They show up only when the column header is clicked on.
- the jqgrid pagination cell `pager_right` is empty. It should display the icons for reload and search
- the jqgrid resize handles do not show up. I'm using

  $("#myjqgrid").jqGrid('gridResize',{minWidth:800,maxWidth:1405,minHeight:350,maxHeight:680});

**I compared the following multiples times but everything seems to be the same**

- CSS
- jqgrid definition

Has anybody else experienced this? Or am I missing something?

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Jquery Grid</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="themes/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="themes/ui.jqgrid.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="themes/ui.multiselect.css" />
        <script src="js/jquery-1.6.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.layout.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
        <script src="plugins/ui.multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="plugins/jquery.tablednd.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="plugins/jquery.contextmenu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <div class="userinfo">
                <table id="myjqgrid"></table>
                <div id="Pager"></div>                  
                <script src="js/myjqgrid.js" type="text/javascript"></script>                   
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JSON**

```
{
    "colModel": [
        {
            "name": "ID",
            "label": "ID",
            "width": 60,
            "align": "left",
            "jsonmap": "cells.0.value",
            "sortable": true      
        },
        {
            "name": "FirstName",
            "label": "FirstName",
            "width": 100,
            "align": "left",
            "jsonmap": "cells.1.value",
            "sortable": false       
        },
        {
            "name": "LastName",
            "label": "LastName",
            "width": 100,
            "align": "left",
            "jsonmap": "cells.2.value",
            "sortable": false       
        }
    ],
    "colNames": [
        "ID",
        "FirstName",
        "LastName"
    ],
    "mypage": {
        "outerwrapper": {
            "page":"1",
            "total":"1",
            "records":"1",
            "innerwrapper": {
                "rows":[
                    {
                        "id":"1",
                        "cells":
                        [               
                            {
                                "value":"12345",
                                "label": "ID"                       
                            },
                            {
                                "value":"David",
                                "label": "FirstName"    
                            },
                            {                           
                                "value":"Smith",
                                "label": "LastName"                         
                            }                                                                                       
                        ]       
                    },
                    {
                        "id":"2",
                        "cells":
                        [               
                            {
                                "value":"37546",
                                "label": "ID"                       
                            },
                            {
                                "value":"Willy",
                                "label": "FirstName"    
                            },
                            {                           
                                "value":"Peacock",
                                "label": "LastName"                         
                            }                                                                                       
                        ]       
                    },
                    {
                        "id":"3",
                        "cells":
                        [               
                            {
                                "value":"62345",
                                "label": "ID"                       
                            },
                            {
                                "value":"Kim",
                                "label": "FirstName"    
                            },
                            {                           
                                "value":"Holmes",
                                "label": "LastName"                         
                            }                                                                                       
                        ]       
                    },
                    {
                        "id":"4",
                        "cells":
                        [               
                            {
                                "value":"186034",
                                "label": "ID"                       
                            },
                            {
                                "value":"Andy",
                                "label": "FirstName"    
                            },
                            {                           
                                "value":"Wills",
                                "label": "LastName"                         
                            }                                                                                       
                        ]       
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**JQGrid Definition (myjquery.js)**

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "myjqgrid.json",
        data: "",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response){
            var columnData = response.mypage.outerwrapper,
                columnNames = response.colNames,
                columnModel = response.colModel;

            $("#myjqgrid").jqGrid({
                datatype: 'jsonstring',
                datastr: columnData,                
                colNames: columnNames,
                colModel: columnModel,
                jsonReader: {
                    root: "innerwrapper.rows",              
                    repeatitems: false
                },
                gridview: true,
                pager: "#Pager",
                rowNum: 2,
                rowList: [2, 4, 6, 8],
                viewrecords: true,              
                recordpos: 'left',
                multiboxonly: true,
                multiselect: true,
                sortname: 'id',
                sortorder: "desc",  
                sorttype: "text",   
                sortable: true,
                caption: "<h2>My JQGrid</h2>",
                width: "1406",      
                height: "100%",
                scrolloffset: 0,    
                loadonce: true,     
                cache: true,
                loadComplete: function(data){

                }
            });
        }
    });
    $("#myjqgrid").jqGrid('navGrid','#Pager');
    $("#myjqgrid").jqGrid('gridResize',{minWidth:800,maxWidth:1405,minHeight:350,maxHeight:680});
});
```

Comment: Do you tried with jqGrid 4.3.1, but some old version of jQuery (<=1.5.3)? Can you provide the demo which reproduces the problem?

Comment: @Oleg: Yes, I tried jqGrid 4.3.1 with jQuery 1.4.3 but it still doesn't work. I have posted my html, json and jqgrid definition code.

Comment: @Oleg: Can you point me as to where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some small problems which follow to the problem.

The first problem. You should move the lines where you call `navGrid` and `gridResize` *inside* of `success` handler. So the navigator and the resizing element of the grid will be created *after* ther grid will be created.

You uses `recordpos: 'left'` which place the text like "View 1-2 of 4" which are typically of the right part of the pager on the left part. Then you called `navGrid` with any additional option. So the `position: 'left'` will be used per default. If the case the navigator bar will be placed *under* the text like "View 1-2 of 4" and one will don't see the navigator icons.

You can fix the problem in two ways. Either you can use `position: 'right'` option

```
$("#myjqgrid").jqGrid('navGrid','#Pager', {position: 'right'});
```

In the case one will receive [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SK11-6.htm):

[image]

or you can remove fix height of the pager with the code

```
$('#Pager').css("height", "auto");
```

see [another demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SK11-6_.htm):

[image]

One more option is just remove `recordpos: 'left'` option and receive the standard navigator and pager layout (see [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SK11-6__.htm)):

[image]

Comment: ... and the sort icons in the column headers... why are they not showing up?

Comment: @SK11: Because you use `sortname: 'id'` and have no column with the name `'id'`. If you would change the parameter to `sortname: 'ID'` you will immediately see the sort icons over the 'ID' column.

Comment: jqgrid reload is not working. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8670490/jqgrid-reload-not-working

Answer (score 2):

For me it was a case of the .png files not getting picked up.  In the jquery-ui.css change your relative reference by putting ../ in the front for example images/xxxxx.png becomes ../images/xxxxxx.png