# jqGrid - setting caption dynamically

Tags: jqgrid

I have the `caption` parameter set in the jqGrid definition. I want to know if there's a way to set it dynamically depending on the `class` attribute of the table element to which the jqGrid plugin is attached.

**HTML 1**

```html
<table id="myjqgrid" class="view"></table>
<div id="Pager"></div>
```

**HTML 2**

```html
<table id="myjqgrid" class="edit"></table>
<div id="Pager"></div>
```

**JQGrid Definition**

```js
$("#myjqgrid").jqGrid({
    caption: ""     // this is what I want to set dynamically
})
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [setCaption](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) method to set new caption on the grid:

```js
var $grid = $('#myjqgrid');
$grid.jqGrid('setCaption', 'newCaption');
```

If you need to set the caption depend on the class of the `<table>` element the code can be like the following

```js
if ($grid.hasClass('edit')) {
    $grid.jqGrid('setCaption', 'Edit Caption');
} else if ($grid.hasClass('vew')) {
    $grid.jqGrid('setCaption', 'View Caption');
} else {
    $grid.jqGrid('setCaption', 'Default Caption');
}
```

The only thing which you can't do with respect of [setCaption](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) method is to remove (to hide) the caption: the results which you have if you created grid without `caption` parameter (or with `caption: ""`). To remove (to hide) the caption you can do

```js
$(">div.ui-jqgrid-titlebar", $grid.closest('div.ui-jqgrid-view')).hide();
```

or

```js
$($grid[0].grid.cDiv).hide();
```

(see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3463002/315935) for details).